# Recent Google Colab issue after upgrade to tensorflow 2.7 in colab

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

When I trained my deep Learning model on Google Colab on Nov 4th 2021, I had no issues, The model was trained in half an hour using GPU instance and then default Tensorflow on Google Colab was 2.6. Now the same code is not working after the default tensorflow version is upgraded to 2.7 in Google Colab. I'm getting OOM error and the my data which is in the shape (16,1024,1024,1) is getting transformed to (16,64,1024,1024). This is not happening on my local (my laptop doesnt have GPU, so its taking very long time to run the same program).
When I tried to downgrade the Tensorflow version on my google
Duplicate of # colab session its giving me CuDnn version incompatibility error.

I want to know if anyone is facing similar issue, how can we rectify it. I have deadlines to meet..

```
ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
(0) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,64,1024,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
[[node model/concatenate/concat
(defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:3224)
]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
```

My source code is taken from https:[//colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/zero_dce.ipynb](https:////colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/zero_dce.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this code again using gpu in colab:

```
Edit - Notebook Setting - GPU - Save
```

As it did not show any error and ran successfully when I executed the same code in `Google colab - gpu` with `TensorFlow version 2.7.0.`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue, it's due to size of my input image, not due to default tensorflow version upgrade. If I resize my input image to the size 512x512 my code is working fine and I'm not getting above issue